# Output redirection in shell script not working completely

Tags: bash, shell

```
>cat test.sh
#!bin/bash
testf="/home/vidya/test/"
cd $testf
`make clean all` >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ -e test ]
then
`./test << end
source(scripts/all.src);
quit;
end` >/dev/null 2>&1
echo -e "\nLog Result is:`grep Tests test.log | tail -1`\n"
fi
```

When I run the above script below is the output.
The problem here is even though I used output redirection while executing test case but still it is printing on console like "Opened file .... " for each file.
It it redirecting most of the test case execution but not completely.
Is there anyway to suppress this output on console ?

```
[vidya ]$ sh test.sh
Opened file </home/vidya/test/scripts/all.src>
Opened file </home/vidya/test/scripts/file1>
Opened file </home/vidya/test/scripts/file2>
.
.
.
Opened file </home/vidya/test/scripts/file10>

Log Result is:    Tests: 1005 PASSED / 48 FAILED
```

Comment: Whe use command substitution here?

Comment: @sjsam If I do not use command substitution output redirection is not possible in script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as sjsam has answered remove the backticks . I think the syntax is like this

```
./test >/dev/null 2>&1 << end
source(scripts/all.src);
quit;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The legacy back-ticks or modern `$()` in bash stands for command substitution ie the output of the what is enclosed in the back-ticks will be executed as it is a command

Change

```
`make clean all` 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

to

```
make clean all >/dev/null 2>&1 # Removed the backticks
```

Instead of output redirection, you could also think about putting

```
exec 1>&3 #making a copy file descriptor 1(stdout) to 3.
exec 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

in the beginning of `test.sh` just after the shebang to run the script silently. Then at the point where you need to start
printing stuff again, revert the settings

```
exec 3>&1 Restoring file descriptor 1 to stdout.
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion & I removed back-tics for make, but the problem here lies in test case execution output redirection.

Comment: @vidya : What I pointed out was indeed a mistake but as you've noted, the `test` script is the bigger concern here. You need to post the content of what it does.

Comment: If I use "exec" then my "echo" is also not printing :(